# SOAP can't load WSDL from wildfly localhost on simple Hello World

Tags: java, soap, wildfly

So I created a very simple class and generated the pom.xml with Maven. Wildfly built the app very quickly without any issues. But when I open new project in SOAP from WSDL with localhost:8080/webapp/Hello it shows that WSDL was not found. I can see the deployed war on wildfly manager.

This is the code that Wildfly returned:

```
 address=http://localhost:8080/webapp/Hello
 implementor=name.packages.Hello
 serviceName={http://name.name/}HelloService
 portName={http://name.name/}HelloPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
```

So it looks alright?

Thats my  main class

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class Hello{
    @WebMethod
    public String hello(@WebParam(name="name") String name){
        return "Hello" + name;
    }
}
```

While adding that URL SOAP returns:
WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.